# How to get substring from given character?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with logins in this form:

```
login1  
domain1\login2  
otherDomain\login3
```

Data is always in form:
DOMAIN\login
or
login

I need to retrieve user logins without prefixes in form (leave everything on right side of '\'):

```
login1  
login2  
login3
```

How to do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Is it possible to have data such as `'abc\xyz\login4'`?

Comment: What did you try? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Take a look at [`CHARINDEX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258228%28SQL.80%29.aspx) and [`RIGHT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238425%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
print substring(@s, charindex('\', @s) + 1, len(@s));
```

This gets the index of the `\` and then adds 1 to get the position after it, and performs a `substring` from that position to past the end of the string (which is OK in SQL 2008 R2).

Comment: Right, it works, thanks.. I've tried similiar method, but I forgot thatfor charindex 'The starting position returned is 1-based, not 0-based.'